# Regex works in JavaScript but not Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I need a regex that can get the company name (in this case "google.com") from this format:
`company=google.com&extension`

According to https://regex101.com/ this should work:
`(?<=company).*(?=&ext)`

However when I try `=REGEXEXTRACT(B3, "(?<=company).*(?=&ext)")` in Google Sheets I get an error:

> Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 2 value "(?<=company).*(?=&ext)" is
> not a valid regular expression.

Ive also tried `=REGEXEXTRACT(B3, "/(?<=company).*(?=&ext)/")`

> Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 2 value "/(?<=company).*(?=&ext)/" is
> not a valid regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `REGEXEXTRACT` function does not support lookarounds so you have to use non-capturing groups for parts that should not be captured and captured groups.

Just use `(?:company)(.*)(?:&ext)` instead of yours. Also, you were using `,`
after `B3`. Do not know which version of Google Sheets you are using but it did not work for me and I had to change it to `;`

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(B3; "(?:company)(.*)(?:&ext)")
```

NOTE: If you're using non-capturing groups then do not forget to use capturing group, otherwise it will return the whole matched values including non-capturing ones as well.

Comment: After I hit enter the ; gets replaced by a , and I also get this error: Error
Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 2 value "(?:company)(.*)(?:&ext)" does not match text of Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 1 value

Comment: When I was using `,` it suggested replacing it with `;`. I think it is just a version depending issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could as well try the following:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(B3,"=(\S*)?&")
```

This should extract only the specific string `google.com` or any word between the `=` sign and the `&` characters.

Comment: I had to change it to "=(\S*)?&e" and then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can match company and capture the part before the ampersand in a group:

```
company=([^\s&]+)&ext
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wEdfEM/1).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One can also use the following

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(B2,"=(.*)&")
```

[image]

Comment: I have to use "=(.*)&e" but then it worked